# New-AzStorageBlobSASToken returns "signature did not match" via powershell

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-powershell

```
$StorageContext = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "https://someblobstorage.blob.core.windows.net/nonpublicfolder" -StorageAccountKey "omghi2u"

New-AzStorageBlobSASToken -Context $StorageContext 
         -Container "nonpublicfolder"
         -Blob 'stuff.zip' 
         -StartTime $(Get-Date) 
         -ExpiryTime $(Get-Date).AddHours(+3) 
         -Permission rl 
         -FullUri 
         -Verbose
```

I use the following powershell command to generate a SAS blob token and link. There are two issues. Firstly it returns a non sensical URL with lots of duplications

```
https://https//someblobstorage.blob.core.windows.net/nonpublicfolder.blob.core.windows.net/nonpublicfolder/stuff.zip?sv=2019-02-02&sr=b&sig=lolsig&st=2019-09-18T06%3A28%3A44Z&se=2019-09-18T09%3A28%3A44Z&sp=rl
```

As you can see it has duplicated the https, and also strangely added blob.core.windows.net multiple times.

If I fix the link by hand to be the following:

```
https://someblobstorage.blob.core.windows.net/nonpublicfolder/stuff.zip?sv=2019-02-02&sr=b&sig=lolsig&st=2019-09-18T06%3A28%3A44Z&se=2019-09-18T09%3A28%3A44Z&sp=rl
```

> `AuthenticationFailed`  Server failed to
>   authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header
>   is formed correctly including the signature. RequestId:some guid
>   Time:2019-09-18T06:30:10.1797787Z 
>    Signature did not match. String to sign
>   used was rl 2019-09-18T06:29:50Z 2019-09-18T09:29:50Z
>   /blob/someblobstorage/somepublicfolder/stuff.zip 2019-02-02 b

Why am I getting an authentication failure?

edit: If I use azure storage explorer to generate it I get a link that has ordered the variables differently, it also works.

```
https://someblobstorage.blob.core.windows.net/nonpublicfolder/stuff.zip?st=2019-09-18T06%3A33%3A04Z&se=2019-09-19T08%3A33%3A00Z&sp=r&sv=2018-03-28&sr=b&sig=somesig
```

How can I generate a working link like the one above using powershell? I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Hi rolls, if the answer is helpful, could you please help mark it as answer? Thanks.

Comment: I had to move on to something else, so I haven't actually got back to testing this again. When I do I will report back. Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Comment: Hello, I'm here just want to check if you have solved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your StorageAccountName is wrong, it should be your storage account name, not a url like "https://someblobstorage.blob.core.windows.net/nonpublicfolder".

From the url(https://someblobstorage.blob.core.windows.net/nonpublicfolder) you provided, it should be `someblobstorage`. Screenshot as below:

[image]

Please use this one(and also change the `someblobstorage` to your real storage account):

```
$StorageContext = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "someblobstorage" -StorageAccountKey "omghi2u"
```